# How to upload file to specific folder within an AWS s3 bucket in node.js

Tags: amazon-s3

Below is my code for uploading a file to an s3 bucket in node.js:

```
Bucket: 'questions'
```

This works fine, however I want to create a folder inside the bucket to save the file to. I have tried the following but received an error:

```
Bucket: 'questions'\'newfolder',
```

Does anyone know how to do this? Many Thanks

Comment: I think bucket is just for the bucket, any additional folder that you want to do then that needs to go with the Key.

Comment: The key understanding here is that S3 doesn't have folders. What you think of as a folder is just an inference from an object's key. An object's key is something like `cat.png` or `cats/white/blanco.png` but it could just as well be `cats%white%blanco.png` where `%` is the common delimiter you use to indicate a hierarchy.